# What is the new way of getting the current user from FirebaseAuth?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a FutureBuilder where the future will be the current user. Flutter is giving me an error with the line I have there now ('The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.'). This works with an older version of the SDK but I cannot find the new version of it. I have tried removing the brackets (just having FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser) but this gives an error 'The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future'. Does anyone know my mistake?

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
    builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot){

    },
  ),
```

Comment: Try removing `()` after currentUser because you INVOKE function instead of passing a reference to it

Comment: That just gives me this error 'The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>'.'

Comment: The `.currentUser` is already made to be `synchronous` (it doesn't return a `Future`). So you won'r be able to use the result of `.currentUser` in a `FutureBuilder` @Eind997

Comment: @void Thanks, what can I use instead?

Comment: You don't need to wait for it. The currentUser is returned immediately @Eind997. The question is marked duplicate and has detailed explanation from marked answer. I advice you check it out. Get the current user like this => `var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser; print(user.uid);`